# What does「という」do in「という方」?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> そろそろ初めての定期テスト**という方**も多いのではないでしょうか。 ([source](https://kou.benesse.co.jp/kou_news/benkyo/0722.html))
>
> まだ持っていない**という方**は是非受験してみてくださいね。
> 連休明けから定期テスト**という方**も多いと思いますのでテスト前に一緒に勉強して目標点を取っちゃいましょう！([source](https://www.eisai.org/sc_ikejiri/blogs/47930))

The meaning of the sentences is pretty clear, but what is the function of という in these sentences? 方{かた} rather than 方{ほう} seems obviously to be the reading of the word.

My research led me to [this Q&A: Imperative form + という方](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/73664/imperative-form-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E6%96%B9) which doesn't appear to be about the same issue.

Comment: These are similar in the sense という is applied to a person.
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/53071/43676
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43727/43676

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「～という」は、『同格』や、「～と言っている」「～という内容の」のような『引用』のほかに、「～という状況・立場の」「～という気持ち・性格の」といったような『説明』にも使われます。例えば、

> 人前で話すのが苦手**という**人
> どうやって勉強したらいいかわからない**という**人

などは、

> 「人前で話すのが苦手な人、苦手な性格の人」
> 「どうやって勉強したらいいかわからない人、わからないと思っている人」

というような意味合いだと考えてよいと思います。

ご質問の例の、

> そろそろ初めての定期テスト**という**方
> まだ持っていない**という**方
> 連休明けから定期テスト**という**方

は、「～という状況の、立場の」というような意味で、

> 「『そろそろ初めての定期テスト(だ)』という（状況の）[方]{かた}」
> 「『まだ持っていない』という（状況の）[方]{かた}」、「まだ持っていない方」
> 「『連休明けから定期テスト(だ)』という（状況の）[方]{かた}」

というような意味合いだと考えてよいと思います。